# I have a php page that uses target"frame1" and it works fine. I want to use post return result so I can use the info inside the iframe

Tags: variables, iframe

This post works fine, runs the php code in txn-sb.php and returns Success or Fail but as it is Inside the iframe1 I can't can't use the info as a variable in this sourse page for other stuff like writing to a data base.

```
<form name="transaction" action="https://my.website.com/txn-sb.php" method="post" target="iframe1" >
                <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>
```

Removing target="iframe1" from the form line takes me to the txn-sb.php and all runs but I want to stay at my source page and just receive the result.

Comment: To receive a result on page you would need to use JavaScript. You can try with AJAX. Logic will depend if submit button is within iframe or your form.

Comment: There is the rub - the txn-sb.php simply returns echo $response; inside the rectangle on my page <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>. I just don't know how to submit the form to grab the php variable $responce from the txn-sb.php page.